# React.js App shows blank page on AWS amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I deployed my app to AWS Amplify and when I connect a custom domain like app.murmurcars.com  browser shows a blank page.
But when I use the domain https://dev6937.d33em1u1ds4zr3.amplifyapp.com browser shows my react.js app.

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

issue was related to SSL certificates, fo some reason i fixed it by deleting existing add and creating new one and adding new ssl certificate

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. there is some issues is going on with SSL in Amplify. fixed it by deleting it and adding new one.

Another solution is to delete the hosted app and create new one